# MVC3 WebGrid: Can htmlAttributes be used on rows/columns?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid

I'm using a WebGrid to create a paged/sortable list in MVC3. I've created an AJAX enabled Delete button which makes the delete call via AJAX, after which I'd like it to remove the row from the table.

The way I'd like to achieve this is by having an `id` or `data-id` attribute on the `<tr>` in the table so that I can easily manipulate it using jQuery. However I can't work out how to add  attributes to rows when using a WebGrid.

I know that attributes can easily set at the grid level like so:
`@grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "gridMapping", style = "width:100%;" },`

However I don't know how to achieve the same at the row/column level.

Comment: ever figure out something nice for this?

Comment: @Maslow I can't remember my final solution now, but it wasn't nice - it worked, but wasn't elegant

Answer (score 1):

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.CheckBox("SelectedInvoice",new { value=item.transactionId})),
   //// rest of your columns here
     )
 )
```

so one way would be putting an HTML helper method in place that can handle your htmlAttributes.
Other way - using combination of format: and Html.Raw 
And the last, but may be the easiest: javascript (jQuery)

so you can try something like :

```
 $('#grid tr').each(function(){
     $(this).attr('yourhtmlattribute','value');
 });
```

and in similar way for TDs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I achieved this

In your webgrid set up add this to one of the colums.

```
grid.Column("UserName", "User Name", format: @<text><span data-id='@item.Id'>@item.UserName</span></text>, canSort: true),
```

No when the HTML grid is rendered you will get this.

```
<tr jQuery45435434="3"> <span data-userid="1">Fred Smith</span></tr>
<tr jQuery45435434="4"> <span data-userid="2">Sally Smith</span></tr>
<tr jQuery45435434="5"> <span data-userid="3">Joe Smith</span></tr>
```